# Android SQLite Range Query

Tags: android, sqlite

I am using this:

```
  String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_QUEST+" WHERE "+KEY_ID+"=40";
```

I want to use range instead of fix like 10 to 20.

Answer (score 1):

You do the same way as on SQL;

```
" WHERE " + KEY_ID + " >= 10 AND " + KEY_ID + " <= 20"
```

[SQL WHERE Clause](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_where.asp)

Comment: Dear this is not working please suggest another way;

"WHERE " + KEY_ID + ">= 10 AND" + KEY_ID + "<= 20" <br> I also used following key;

"WHERE " + KEY_ID + ">= 10 +"AND" + KEY_ID + "<= 20""

Comment: What you mean to say?

Comment: Maybe was an space before the WHERE, try again,I've edited. If it doesn't work post the full query you are trying.

Comment: String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_QUEST+" WHERE "+KEY_ID+ ">= 10 AND" +KEY_ID+ "<= 20";

Comment: Can you confirm that is working using only on id (40) ?

Comment: yes it is working on single  value with = sign.. KEY_ID range is 1-400..

Comment: Probably space issues again, I've edited (once again!), if doesn't work put Log.i("QUERY", selectQuery); after this line and post the result.

Answer (score 0):

To check whether some value is between some other values, use the [BETWEEN operator](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html#between):

```java
String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM "+TABLE_QUEST+" WHERE "+KEY_ID+" BETWEEN 10 AND 20";
```